# Javascript dynamic nested object

Tags: javascript, object, dynamic, nested

My goal is to generate serialized objects in the main object.
A solar system is my idea of nesting where I can access a variable by calling it like

```
universe.system1.planet4.x
```

universe > system > planet > etc

Im stuck on generating anything thats nested. So far I can only get 1 level of nesting to work correctly.

```
setInterval(onTimerTick, 1000); 
function onTimerTick() {

var entityCount=4;
  for (i=1; i<entityCount;i++){
    console.log('system' + i)
    universe['planet'+i]=[entityCount,entityCount,entityCount,entityCount];  
  }//entitycounts in object are placeholder for more data
 console.log(universe);
}

var universe = {
}
```

Output

```
Object {
  system0: [5, 5, 5, 5],
  system1: [5, 5, 5, 5],
  system2: [5, 5, 5, 5],
  system3: [5, 5, 5, 5]
}
```

Anytime I try to add any nesting it won't generate.

Comment: im confused what are you trying to do, your function does what your output states

Comment: So far I can only get 1 level of nesting to work correctly.My goal is to be able to go 3,4,5 or more levels of nesting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this something like this?

You would have to create `X` nested loops, with `X` being the number of nested levels you want to create.

```js
const nbSystem = 5;
const nbPlanetPerSystem = 3;

// Create the base
const universe = {};

// Generate systems
for (let i = 0; i < nbSystem; i += 1) {
  universe[`system${i + 1}`] = {};

  // Generate planets
  for (let j = 0; j < nbPlanetPerSystem; j += 1) {
    universe[`system${i + 1}`][`planet${j + 1}`] = 'something';
  }
}

console.log(universe);

console.log(universe.system3.planet3);
```

Comment: OH I need to make another for loop to go back and access the previously generated object, dude ive spent days going in circles on this thank you so much!! #jrdevlife